# Remote Redis connection slow

Tags: php, drupal-7, redis

I am experimenting with using Redis for a Drupal website, hosted on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have installed the [redis](https://www.drupal.org/project/redis) drupal module and am using the [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) library. I have also installed the 'redis-server' Ubuntu package and left the default configuration.

Configuring the Drupal site to use Redis for its cache backend works fine and the pages are lightning fast.

The problem arrives when I tried to spark up an [m3.medium](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) AWS instance and hosting the redis server there. The reason behind this is so that we can use  one redis server and connect to it from multiple servers (live website hosted on multiple instances behind a load balancer, so each instance should connect to the same redis server).

I have set up the redis server on the instance, modified the redis.conf file to bind the correct IP address so it can be accessed from the outside, opened up the 6379 port, then tried connecting to it from my local computer

```
redis-cli -h IP
```

It worked fine so I decided to flip my local site's configuration to point to the new redis server.
The moment I did that the site became painfully slow, and at first I thought it might not even load at all. After almost a minute it finally loaded the home page. Clicking around the site was almost as slow, but the time reduced to maybe 10-15 seconds. That it still unacceptable and doesn't even compare to the lightning fast page load when using the redis server.

My question is: is there some specific configuration I need to do to make the remote connection faster? Is there something preventing it from performing well? some bottleneck somewhere?

Let me know if you want me to add the drupal settings.php configuration, although I am using a pretty standard config.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such setting - you can try connecting to a free Redis Cloud's instance (disclaimer: I work at Redis Labs) to rule out any misconfs. Also, try running a Redis benchmarking utility from your app server to your Redis server (locally and on the cloud) - the numbers could be telling

Comment: my idea was to have one server running redis, and then 2 or 3 webservers hosting a drupal site that would connect to that redis server. or should i just install redis on each webserver? i might give redis cloud a try. thanks

Comment: Installing Redis on each web server is possible but kind of beats the purpose of Redis... You'd be better (and faster) off if you just use hashmaps in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Although I ran the same configuration for a php application as you are trying, I had no issues hosting redis on either a small or medium instance and handling large amounts of traffic.  There must be a config issue somewhere.  Another option to debug it would be to try switching to Elasticcache (AWS' redis offering) it requires that all clients be within the same region, but could make finding your problem very easy.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I am considering trying out Elasticcache as well, but for now Redis seems to do the job really well. I think there might be something wrong with connecting to the remote server from my local. I set up the configuration on the stager environment and enabled caching with Redis and it worked really well and site is much faster now. Deployed it to live as well and it's lightning fast.